# Scrolling within modal div without scrolling the entire page

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I have a webpage with some content. I then have a modal that pops up over.

The issue I am having is when I try to scroll the contents within the modal only the contents behind scroll.

Here's the CSS:

```
html, body {
    background: blue;
    margin: 0px;
}

/* Content Behind */
.content {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    z-index: 100;
}

/* Modal Above */
#modal {
    background: yellow;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 200;
    overflow: scroll;
    display: none;
    padding: 5px;
}

.show {
    display: block !important;
}
```

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chriswatts91/hj5jfjbg/5/)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/hj5jfjbg/6/)

You havent specified height for `#modal`.. Update your CSS as follows

```
#modal {
    background: yellow;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    height:100%;     /*<<<<<<<<<specify height>>>>>>>>*/
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 200;
    overflow: scroll;
    display: none;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

**UPDATE**

To prevent the content behind from scrolling when the modal is open, you have to change your Javascript a little bit.

Please see the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/hj5jfjbg/8/) for that.

Changed JS is as below

```
var bodyElems = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
var body = bodyElems[0];
body.style.overflow = "hidden";

document.getElementById('openModal').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("modal").className = "show";
    body.style.overflow = "hidden";

};

document.getElementById('closeModal').onclick = function () {
    document.getElementById("modal").className = "";
    body.style.overflow = "auto";
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Is is possible to prevent the content behind from scrolling completely when the modal is open? As it is, when you scroll to the bottom on the modal it begins to scroll the entire page...

Answer (score 1):

You didn't have set a fixed height to the modal.

Try this:

```
#modal {
    background: yellow;
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px; // Here you set the height of your choice
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    z-index: 200;
    overflow: scroll;
    display: none;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kxrq5oou/)